# C# linq lambda select from group not working

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list, I need to find out which name group doesn't have server A

```
var list = new[]
        {
            new { name = "object1", server="A"},
            new { name = "object1", server="B"},
            new { name = "object2", server="B"},
            new { name = "object2", server="C"},
            new { name = "object3", server="B"},
            new { name = "object3", server="A"},
            new { name = "object4", server="C"},
        };

var selectServerANotPresent = list.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(g => g.name, (key, k) => k.Where(s => s.server == "A"))
            .Where(w => w.Count() == 0)
            .Select(s=>s.FirstOrDefault()) //My issue is in this line
            .ToList();

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", selectServerANotPresent));
```

It's returning a list of 2 items with NULL entries. How do I make this print out like below?

```
{ name="object2", server="B" }
{ name="object4", server="C" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently discarding all non-server-A objects when you do the grouping. (By the time you get to the line where your comment says you *think* the problem is, you're looking at an empty group.)

Instead, just group by name and make the *filtering* part check whether the group contains any server-A values:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

var data = new[]
{
    new { Name = "object1", Server = "A"},
    new { Name = "object1", Server = "B"},
    new { Name = "object2", Server = "B"},
    new { Name = "object2", Server = "C"},
    new { Name = "object3", Server = "B"},
    new { Name = "object3", Server = "A"},
    new { Name = "object4", Server = "C"},
};
var selectServerANotPresent = data
    .GroupBy(o => o.Name)
    .Where(group => !group.Any(o => o.Server == "A"))
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .ToList();

selectServerANotPresent.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Output:

```
{ Name = object2, Server = B }
{ Name = object4, Server = C }
```